# React-native android WebView handle clicked Url before loading

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, webview, react-native

I'm showing a Website trough a WebView in react-native. On this Website there is a link to a PassWallet (.pkpass) file (not the only use case). When I click on any link on this Website I want to check whether it is an other Website or a .pkpass file or whatever. While this check is running I don't want to load anything, just wait until my function is finished and I'm knowing if I should open a Website or open another app or whatever. I want to make this on the JavaScript side because my whole routing functions are there and in my opinion react-native was built for this cases :-)

On iOS there is this beautiful function `onShouldStartLoadWithRequest` which exactly does what I need.

```
_onShouldStartLoadWithRequest(e) {

    if(checkUrl(e.url)) {

        let Router = this.props.navigator.props.router;
        let route = Router.getRouteFromUrl(e.url);
        this.props.navigator.push(route);

        return false;

    }

    return true;
}
```

I'm getting the event (e) and can check what url it's trying to load. I can even check with e.navigationType if it was a click or whatever.

Now on Android this function does not exists. On the native side there is the function `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` but this function is not implemented in react-native. 
I found the following GitHub issue / PR https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/6478 
I guess now, because this issue is closed and there are explanations for therefore, this function don't get implemented.

So I started to find a way by myself. I created a Native UI Component which displays a WebView and then implement this method.

CustomWebViewManager.java:

```
package ch.mypackage;

import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import com.facebook.react.uimanager.SimpleViewManager;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp;

public class CustomWebViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<CplusWebView> {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "CplusWebView";
    }

    @Override
    protected CustomWebView createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
        return new CustomWebView(reactContext);
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "url")
    public void setUrl(CustomWebView view, @Nullable String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "javascriptEnabled")
    public void setJavascriptEnabled(CustomWebView view, boolean enabled) {
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(enabled);
    }

}
```

CustomWebView.java

```
package ch.couponplus;

import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.events.EventDispatcher;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.events.RCTEventEmitter;

public class CustomWebView extends WebView {

    EventDispatcher eventDispatcher;
    EventWebClient eventWebClient;

    public CustomWebView(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        eventWebClient = new EventWebClient();
        setWebViewClient(eventWebClient);
    }

    protected class EventWebClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            WritableMap event = Arguments.createMap();
            event.putString("message", "MyMessage");
            ReactContext reactContext = (ReactContext)getContext();
            reactContext.getJSModule(RCTEventEmitter.class).receiveEvent(
                    getId(),
                    "topChange",
                    event);

            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

It works as expected. I can now trigger the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` function in JS and make logs or whatever.

But my question is how can I now set `true` or `false` in Javascript to control my `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` function? And is there a possibility to make my own functions available? Until now I only managed to trigger the `onChange` event?

I just want to make the same as I made in iOS. Maybe someone comes up and tells me that this isn't possible for whatever reason but how should I or how do you handle cases like this? I know there are Url schemas but so much I know they don't work in this case.

Answer (score 9):

> I'm showing a Website trough a WebView in react-native. On this
>   Website there is a link to a PassWallet (.pkpass) file (not the only
>   use case). When I click on any link on this Website I want to check
>   whether it is an other Website or a .pkpass file or whatever.

I had a similar issue as well, where I wanted to check the type of link clicked within the webView of my react-native app.  Like you said, on the iOS side the function `onShouldStartLoadWithRequest`, which is not present on the Android side.

This was my solution on the Android side.

```
   <WebView
        source={{uri: this.props.url}}
        onLoad={this.onLoad.bind(this)}
        onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={this._onShouldStartLoadWithRequest}
        onNavigationStateChange = {this._onShouldStartLoadWithRequest} 
    />
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
  _onShouldStartLoadWithRequest(e) {

if(checkUrl(e.url)) {

    let Router = this.props.navigator.props.router;
    let route = Router.getRouteFromUrl(e.url);
    this.props.navigator.push(route);

    this.refs[WEBVIEW_REF].stopLoading();  // <---- Add a similar line
    //This will tell your webView to stop processing the clicked link

    return false;

}

return true;
```

If I understood your problem correctly, you want a way to check the URL clicked in your WebView and then decide based on the URL to proceed or stop and do something else.  The solution above the way I handled it in our app.

Check out the links below:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#stoploading
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/6886

Comment: thanks for your answer. this is a really good solution I'm using this in other cases for example when there is a link and I want it to open in my own view and not in the webbrowser. But if you want to open a link who is not targeted to a webpage like a .pkpass file the app crashes because it's starting to load the link before you can stop it. With the iOS function you can stop the request before any action is performed. As far as I could test this case `onNavigationStateChange` gets called after a first load request. Or did you find a way to stop the loading when you click on an invalid link?

Comment: The only way I can think of solving this is to stop the loading the webview by using the `stopLoading` function.  But then you say `onNavigationStateChage` is getting called after the load request.. so by the time `stopLoading()` is called - it might be too late and the app would have crashed. 

But I'd try it once to see if the above solution works.

Comment: I can't exactly say which function gets called on which time but I can see that the app crashes before I can stop it as soon as I want to open a link like a `.pkpass`

Answer (score 2):

`onShouldStartLoadWithRequest` has been supported since end-2018 in [`react-native-community/react-native-webview`](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview) version. [See PR](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/pull/107).