# React Native WebView onShouldStartLoadWithRequest for android

Tags: android, react-native, android-webview

What I'm trying to achieve is basically something like android web view's shouldOverrideUrlLoading. I'm loading a specific URL into the web view which in turn have a series of redirects. The goal is to intercept the last URL and handle it by the application instead of the WebView component. It seems that something similar is available for the ios platform (onShouldStartLoadWithRequest) but didn't get to the android yet (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/6478).

The workaround I've tried is to use onNavigationStateChange, parsing the URL and stopping the web view loading if needed:

```
  onNavigationStateChange = (navState) => {

    const url = new URL(navState.url);
    const lastSegment = url.pathname.substr(url.pathname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    // Handle the get token ourselvs
    if (lastSegment === GETTOKEN) {
      this.refs[WEBVIEW_REF].stopLoading();
      this.getToken()
    }

    this.setState({
      url: navState.url,
      backButtonEnabled: navState.canGoBack
    });
  }
```

The problem is that the stopLoading function is not really working in my case. I see that while executing the async function getToken() the browser continues the loading of the last URL.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: I hope you found a solution to your problem... I have the same issue and made a lot of researches and a big SO post so maybe this will help you in any way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999499/react-native-android-webview-handle-clicked-url-before-loading I have done it in a way like this but it's not the best way. The best way would be to implement onShouldOverrideUrlLoading on android but this seems to be impossible for some reasons...

Comment: For anyone wondering, now https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview supporst this cross platform