# Debugging WebView in React Native apps

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, webview

I have a React Native App that uses WebView to render an HTML page from the assets. The page has some javascript that does some processing. The problem is that I cannot see the `console.log` statements from the web view. I have tried the Chrome Remote [Remote Debugging WebViews](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews)

Here's how the code looks like. Note that for Android, I am trying to supply some native props to enable debugging.

```
import React from 'react';
import Expo from 'expo';
import { WebView } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const htmlURL = Expo.Asset.fromModule(require('./assets/index.html')).uri;
    return (
      <WebView nativeConfig={{props: {webContentsDebuggingEnabled: true}}}  
      source={{uri: htmlURL}} />
    );
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Any ideas around how that might work will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried expo XDE @Mohsin Hijazee

Answer (score 36):

The easiest way to inspect your WebView in React Native is to just use the [Remote JS Debugger.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#chrome-developer-tools) This has the added benefit for working in either iOS or Android, since you're simply debugging the JavaScript that is running on your application.

In order to see the WebViews, you'll want to go a step further and use [Chrome's Remote Devices](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/webviews/).

[image: DevTools Chrome]

If you click on Inspect next to your Document matching the `index.html` you're wanting to debug, you can then see all of the logs in the console for that WebView.

[image]

I added a `<script>` inside of `index.html` in the `<header>` that just does the following:

`console.log('This is showing in the console!')`

You can see in the image above, its logging out in the DevTools that is inspecting that WebView.

For more on react-native-webview debugging guide head on to [Debugging Guide Docs](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Debugging.md)

Comment: This is a little clunky, but I’m pretty sure it’s the best solution available in React Native right now.

Comment: as you mention, how can I set [Chrome's Remote 
 Devices](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews) config? where should I put that code? can you plz share your code.i stuck since 2 days.

Comment: The link you gave says one must enable WebView debugging by calling the static method setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled. You can't do that without ejecting expo, can you? So there is no way for an expo project to debug webview without ejecting?

Comment: It has been deprecated.

Comment: I can't find "Remote Devices" in the list. Can someone confirm this still works for iOS? The chrome doc specifies Android.

Comment: As of today, for Android at least, you just need to add <WebView webviewDebuggingEnabled={true} ...
See https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#webviewdebuggingenabled

Answer (score 20):

Not sure if it's relevant for your case, but if you're also developing for iOS there's a pretty easy way to do it on a Mac + iOS simulator (or a real device). At the end, a React Native `WebView` creates a native web-view (`UIWebView` on iOS, and a `WebView` on Android), so any debugging method which works for web apps applies here as well.

1. On your iOS simulator (or device): Open the settings app -> Safari -> Advanced -> Turn Web inspector ON.
2. Open Safari on your Mac and enable developer mode in: Preferences -> Advanced -> Show developer menu in menu bar (checkbox at the bottom).
3. In Safari on your mac you will now have the "Develop" menu. Open it and find the Simulator or your connected device. When you hover this menu item you will see the currently loaded page. This works for any page loaded on the device, whether it's shown in a `WebView` inside your app or on the system browser.
4. Once you select the page, you can use the Safari Web Inspector to pretty much do anything: view all loaded resources, network requests, highlight elements, console logs, debug the JS code and more.

Comment: Thanks, this is a helpful tip but wouldn’t work for my purposes since I needed to debug at initialization time and couldn’t click the web view fast enough :)

Comment: @AaronBrager you can hit the reload button in mac safari and you'll see the init logs

Comment: I tried this, and it worked for web pages opened in Safari, but did not work for pages in WebView.

Comment: Edit: the above comment is about pages opened in a real device. If in the Simulator, both Safari and WebView can work. I upvoted you. :)

Comment: @Betty great. I just want to suggest that you check that "Web Inspector" in Safari advanced settings on you device is enabled. For me it works for devices, as well as for simulators

Comment: @Artal Have you found a way to get access to props in the console via this method?

Comment: Not sure what has changed, but I cant see a network tab anymore when debugging with safari. This method also doesn't work if the webview is hidden.

Comment: I can't seem to find "Turn Web inspector ON" in Safari's Advanced options. iPhone 12, iOS 14.5.

Answer (score 6):

In recent Chrome versions, you can simply enable Debug mode in the React Native app, then navigate to `chrome://inspect/#devices`.

In the Devices tab, find the entry "WebView in ....." that corresponds to your application, and click "Inspect" to view the debugger.

[image]

Comment: Really interesting but doesnn't seem to work with Expo. Hope somebody else has more luck.

Answer (score 4):

I propose to unify `javascript's` console messages (`console.log`) and `logcat` of Android into one [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html) which can be viewed with [Monitor].(https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-basics.html). It can be helpful to have console messages and `WebView` messages in one place, especially when you have race conditions/timing problems, so you can see the order of events. Monitor also allows you to apply filters, to select which messages you see. iOS users can also fond this helpful.

Here is an example:
[image]
See [CustomWebViewManager and CustomWebView in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999499/react-native-android-webview-handle-clicked-url-before-loading) for some background on how to customize `WebView` in [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) (a `JavaScript library` for building user interfaces. "It is maintained by `Facebook`, `Instagram` and a community of individual developers and corporations" [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)) ).

Info: [WebChromeClient](http://therockncoder.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/understanding-androids-webchromeclient.html) lets you handle `Javascript's` `console.log("message")` 
 {via `onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm)`}, `alert()` and other functions.

Catching JavaScript's console messages:

```
//find or get your React Native webView or create a CustomWebView
WebView webView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);

//by setting a WebClient to catch javascript's console messages:
// and relay them to logcat (view in monitor) or do what you want with them
WebChromeClient webChromeClient = new WebChromeClient() {
        public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
            Log.d(TAG, cm.message() + " -- From line "
                    + cm.lineNumber() + " of "
                    + cm.sourceId() );
            return true;
        }
    });

webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
```

The problem with [cross platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-platform) support is the [Virtual Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) and the associated [Sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security)).
I think `react-native` *tries* to be very pure `JavaScript` (but fails, `JavaScript` as a language is pure, the *implementations* never are, always about compromise). My personal preference for cross platform support is [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `window.postMessage` from inside your WebView and the `onMessage` prop of the WebView component:

In your html:

```
...
window.postMessage(stringMessage, '*');
...
```

In your react native component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Expo from 'expo';
import { WebView } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  handleMessage = (event) => {
     console.log(event.nativeEvent.data);
  }
  render() {
    const htmlURL = Expo.Asset.fromModule(require('./assets/index.html')).uri;
    return (
      <WebView nativeConfig={{props: {webContentsDebuggingEnabled: true}}}  
      source={{uri: htmlURL}}
      onMessage={this.handleMessage}
      />
    );
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: What about runtime errors? Any chance to see them? I mean, maybe a try/catch would do, but I wonder if there's an alternative way to access the error stream.

Answer (score 0):

For someone trying to do this on mac for ios simulator or connected device:
=> Use safari technology preview->Develop->Simulator-> nativeapp

both jsContext and Webview will be visible to open for debugging + console.
This provides all typical debugger features.

Bonus: you can even use window for jscontext to trouble shoot react native classes etc. for example in your app class add "window.app = this;" then you can access your app class object through console.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add that the official `react-native-webview` library has a section on [Debugging](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Debugging.md) that you might find helpful!