# Javascript console.log() in a React Native WebView

Tags: react-native

I have a WebView in my React Native app, and I need to show the logs from the Javascript that is executed within the WebView inside my React Native app.

I think that I need to play around with WebView's `nativeConfig` prop to achieve this, but I don't know how to make it work.

Here is my latest attempt:

```
 <WebView
    nativeConfig={{
      props: {
        webContentsDebuggingEnabled: true,
        console: new MyLogger()
      }
    }}
   ...

class MyLogger {
  log = message => {
    console.log(message); // Print in RN logs for now...
  };   
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this is basically a duplicate of this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47711418/debugging-webview-in-react-native-apps?rq=1. Have a look, there are some great answers there. The easiest one for me was debugging WebView when running inside the simulator using Safari dev tools.

Comment: @ needsleep Thanks for your comment, but I want the logs within the React Native app, so that I can show them to the user within the mobile app itself. Remote debugging is not what I seek to do.

Comment: sorry didn't realise that :). Then you're right, postMessage is the way to go.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok I figured it out after all. I just need to inject some code to the WebView, and have it use my own version of console.

```
const debugging = `
     // Debug
     console = new Object();
     console.log = function(log) {
       window.webViewBridge.send("console", log);
     };
     console.debug = console.log;
     console.info = console.log;
     console.warn = console.log;
     console.error = console.log;
     `;


<WebView
  injectedJavaScript={debugging}
  onMessage={this.onMessage}
```

I then get the console logs inside the onMessage function.

Comment: Just to update this answer: with `react-native-webview`, you can replace `window.webViewBridge.send("console", log);` by `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(log)`

Answer (score 15):

If you're using Webview v5 or above, then you can use something similar to this:

```js
const debugging = `
  const consoleLog = (type, log) => window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify({'type': 'Console', 'data': {'type': type, 'log': log}}));
  console = {
      log: (log) => consoleLog('log', log),
      debug: (log) => consoleLog('debug', log),
      info: (log) => consoleLog('info', log),
      warn: (log) => consoleLog('warn', log),
      error: (log) => consoleLog('error', log),
    };
`;

const onMessage = (payload) => {
  let dataPayload;
  try {
    dataPayload = JSON.parse(payload.nativeEvent.data);
  } catch (e) {}

  if (dataPayload) {
    if (dataPayload.type === 'Console') {
      console.info(`[Console] ${JSON.stringify(dataPayload.data)}`);
    } else {
      console.log(dataPayload)
    }
  }
};

<WebView
  injectedJavaScript={debugging}
  onMessage={onMessage}
/>
```

The difference from the accepted question is that webview changed how you post message. [More here](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/releases/tag/v5.0.0)

Comment: don't know it's not logging anything on the console 

Comment: There's an issue with this. If the web app uses console.log with multiple parameters it will cause this injected code to hang the application.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to @Caesar's solution above, if you replace `onMessage` as shown below, this is working nice:

```
const onMessage = (event) => {
event.persist();
let dataPayload;
try {
  dataPayload = JSON.parse(event.nativeEvent.data);
} catch (e) {}

if (dataPayload) {
  if (dataPayload.type === "Console") {
    console.info(`[Console] ${JSON.stringify(dataPayload.data)}`);
  } else {
    console.log(dataPayload);
  }
}
```

};

Comment: I see the error in my code. I just fixed it. Thanks :)