# How to view console.log() of webpage running inside React Native WebView?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, webview

In my React Native code, I'm try to call my webpage inside WebView component. In that webpage I'm passing some data using **window.postMessage()** method from **injectedJavascript** attribute of React Native WebView. Based upon the data that I've passed to my web page, I'm displaying some **console.log()** on that page. So, my requirement is to capture those console logs from my webpage inside WebView component and display it in my React Native Code.

Below is my WebView Code:

```
<WebView
  source={{
      uri: 'https://www.example.com/',
  }}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
  injectedJavaScript={`window.postMessage({...}, '*')`}
  onMessage={(event) => {
      const { data } = event.nativeEvent;
      console.log('MESSAGE >>>>' + JSON.stringify(data));
  }}
/>
```

In short, whatever is print in the console of my webpage, I want to print that in my React Native's console, so that I can able to debug my webpage from WebView component by passing the data using **window.postMessage()**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript console.log() in a React Native WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53560744/javascript-console-log-in-a-react-native-webview)

Comment: I have already tried that code, but after that changes my **window.postMessage()** is not working.