# React native webview files are not loading in ios device, but loading fine in simulator

Tags: react-native

Im storing the local file in xcode,files are loading in simulator but not loading in ios device

im using react-native-webview version 5.0.1, in my webview im passing sourse as  {uri: 'ICF-Package/ICFPackage/index.html'}

```
<WebView
                source={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 
                {uri: 'ICF-Package/ICFPackage/index.html'} :
                { uri: 'file:///android_asset/ICF-Package/ICFPackage/index.html' }
              }
                    ref={(webView) => this.webView = webView}
                    originWhitelist={'["*"]'}
                    javaScriptEnabled={true}
                    domStorageEnabled={true}
                    startInLoadingState={true}
                    useWebKit = {true}
                    //scalesPageToFit={true}
                    scrollEnabled={false}
                    onLoad={() => this.sendPostMessage()}
                    allowFileAccess={true}
                    allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
                    allowFileAccessFromFileURLs={true}
                    allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
                    mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={true}
                 />
```

im not getting any error message but files are not loading in real device

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that helps you to debug WebViews a bit deeper if running at your Device: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48572797/1256697

But as little Workaround for local files, you could try to use the 'html' parameter instead the 'uri' Parameter for IOS:

```
const myHTML = require('./ICF-Package/ICFPackage/index.html');
<WebView
  source={PolicyHTML}
  style={{flex: 1}}
 />
```

Also see: https://aboutreact.com/load-local-html-file-url-using-react-native-webview/

But maybe the cleanest way to solve it for IOS is to put a copy of your html-File in `Project > resources > index.html` and link it like that with your Webview:

```
<WebView
  style={{flex: 1}}
  originWhitelist={['*']}
  source={'./resources/index.html'}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
  domStorageEnabled={true}
/>
```